# Server 2008 32-bit on Azure

Tags: windows, 32-bit

I'm trying to setup a VM on Azure. The VM is windows server 2008 32-bit. I cant seem to find the image for it. any help is appreciated. I've tried to look for the correct image in the market place and I have only x64 options for which don't work in my case. Do you know of a work-around?

Comment: You are aware that 32 bit sql server for any production use was retired - hm - 10 years ago or so? Workaround: 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, there are no Server 2008 images in the Marketplace.

From [Microsoft server software support for Microsoft Azure virtual machines](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines):

> For versions that are earlier than Windows Server 2008 R2, there is no Azure Marketplace support, and customers must provide their own images.

You can create a VM running Server 2008, but you have to create an image and upload it yourself.

From [Support for 32-bit operating systems in Azure virtual machines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/support-32-bit-operating-systems-virtual-machines):

> Microsoft Azure now allows users to bring in their 32-bit Windows Operating systems over to Azure. As some of these operating systems have already reached their end of life supportability agreement, Microsoft might not offer additional support for them.